# xpath with multiple contains statements do not function correctly

Tags: xpath, contains

I have html code as follows below.  I am trying to access it with selenium.  If I do a

```
//*[contains(text(),'Add OfficeContract (Portal)')]
```

it finds several (there is more html that has more occurrences).  So I want to find a specific instance but when I try

```
//*[contains(text(),'Add OfficeContract (Portal)') and contains(text(),'7121995')]
```

There are no matches found.  SImpy doing

```
//*[contains(text(),'7121995')]
```

Finds all sorts of stuff (html is full of that string)

HTML CODE

```
<tr class="pd" valign="top"><br>
<td> </td><br>
<td nowrap="">SQAAUTO</td><br>
<td nowrap="">01/30/2014 9:47:48 AM</td><br>
<td><br>
<b>Add OfficeContract (Portal)</b><br>
<br><br>
Office Id 7121995<br>
<br><br>
Contract ID added: "8976504"<br>
<br><br>
Term Date added: "12/31/9999"<br>
<br><br>
</td><br>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that the two strings are not found together in the same element (based on your sample).

For the above xpath to return a result you would need an element like this:

```
<b>Add OfficeContract (Portal) 7121995</b>
```